# raspberry pi C program xxxx segmentation fault

Tags: linux, gcc, debian, raspberry-pi

I have made a C program, compiled with gcc , combined with some bash scripts, for playing music using mpd/mpc from web & usb.

It works well.

But at times the program exits after a while with

```
xxxx segmentation fault
```

where xxxx is a 4 digit number.

Can someone tell me what this means & how to fix it ?

Thanks !

Edited: The number before the message is random, so replaced with xxxx

Comment: where is the program?

Comment: Arun,   I thought there would be a specific situation when this message is shown ?      How do I share my files ?    Upload to dropbox and post the link here ?     I must point out that I have an LCD & 5 keys connected to the GPIOs of the Pi (as a user interface).

Comment: Sounds like the numbers might be the process ID. No, this is pretty much the most generic error message you can get (perhaps apart from "bus error" which is also misleading). It means your program somehow accesses invalid memory. Typically a pointer variable in your code is uninitialuzed or corrupted.

Comment: It's curious that it does not crash at the 1st run... it runs for quite some time before crashing. Anyways, besides reading through my code line by line, is there any way or tool that can trap this error ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, after reading through my code.

There was an external program I was calling regularly by means of the 'popen' function.

But I forgot to add the corresponding 'pclose' function !

So, after some time there were too many files open, and my application was terminated.

After doing the correction, I left my application running overnight, and in the morning, it was still running !.

This was the longest it had run without crashing.

So I believe that was the source of the problem.

Edit: its been 24 Hrs that my application has been running without crashing, so I'l have to mark this as the answer.